Redis TimeSeries TS.MADD delay
I am using node.js and Redis TimeSeries. I need to add real-time crypto trading data (around 300 coins) to Redis TimeSeries. The task must be completed within a few milliseconds. I am using the TS.MADD command with pipelining and TCP_NODELAY options. I have noticed that 99% of the data is added in less than 5 milliseconds, but one or two records experience a delay until the very end of the second (around 990 ms) before being added. System resources are utilized at less than 5%, everything is happening on the same server, so there is no network delays. I need to find out how to complete the entire TS.MADD task without this delay.

Start by checking your SLOWLOG to separate the query execution time from other factors.

that's the only query running.

I had the same issue (appears we are working on the same project;), I was running SLOWLOG as suggested by Lior, and figured that I am running some ts().info queries that clog the inserts.
Setup:
I am using a pipeline that runs every second to optimize for load.
This results in 200-500 timeseries values sent to redis at a time.
After removing any ts.info queries it appears the madd inserts are available almost instantly (1 second delay + some latency).
My recommendation is to send the data directly to your client if you need a latency of milliseconds and use redis only as a buffer/store/aggregator.
Let's say you want a client to connect to this data, the client reads the latest trades from redis timeseries and then receive new data directly via socket.
